# How do I find the pressure that would be present in carbon dioxide for this problem?

Tags: equilibrium

Problem:

For the reaction below, Keq = 0.0064 (at 825C).  If you place 12.011 g Carbon and 5 atm pressure of water vapour in a 2.0 L reaction flask, calculate the pressure of carbon dioxide gas that will be present once the reaction comes to equilibrium.

C(s)  + 2 H2O(g)  ↔  CO2(g)  +  2 H2(g)

Here is what I have done so far:

[image]

\begin{array}{l}K_{eq}=\frac{P\left(CO_2\right)\cdot P\left(H_2\right)}{P\left(H_2O\right)}=0.0064\ \ \left(at\ 825\ \text{°C}\right)\\\frac{\left(x\right)\left(2x\right)}{\left(5-2x\right)}=0.0064\\\frac{2x^2}{5-2x}=0.0064\\2x^2=0.0064\left(5-2x\right)\\2x^2=0.032-0.0128x\\2x^2+0.0128x-0.032=0\\x\ =0.1233\\∴\ \text{The pressure of carbon dioxide is 0.1233 atm}\end{array}

I have gotten the answer to be 0.1233 atm but the answer is supposed to 0.3 atm. So, did I do something wrong here? Could someone help me out here if possible?

Comment: Using photos/screenshots of ( even handwritten) text instead of typed text itself is strongly discouraged. It is impossible to index/search/reuse it in answers referring to it. In a  case  of handwritten text, it puts extra burden on responders to properly decipher it.
That all may lead to the question being ignored or even closed.
 Consider copy/paste or retyping and using eventually  [MathJax](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86/how-can-i-format-math-chemistry-expressions-here) for expressions and formulas.

Comment: Similarly as in your prior question, you ignore power coefficients of pressures in the equilibrium expression.

Comment: What power coefficients are you implying? @Poutnik

Comment: Yes, Sir, I know the general formula for the equilibrium constant as evident from my answer, but the idea that I want to know is how the answer is 0.3 atm and where did I make a mistake. I am sure it is a very simple mistake that I made, so if you could point that out to me or anyone else, that would be great. Likewise, knowing what I did wrong here, I can have a better understanding of how to do questions like this in the future. I hope you understand. @Poutnik

Comment: No, you do not. Think and search again.

Comment: Sir, the formula for the equilibrium constant is evident at the first step of my solution. If there is anything wrong with that, let me know. @Poutnik

Comment: You should stop asking and start searching.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equilibrium_constant

Comment: Okay, Sir, I will start searching... But really I just want to know that little mistake that I made.

Comment: Or here https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry_Textbook_Maps/Supplemental_Modules_(Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry)/Equilibria/Chemical_Equilibria/The_Equilibrium_Constant

Comment: If you find your mistake yourself, it gives you more, than if you are just told. BTW, the site prefers teaching fishing to giving fish.

Comment: Yes, I understand, Sir, as you said, "I should stop asking and start searching". That was what I was doing some time ago, but I greatly appreciate you giving me a head start. Thanks.

Comment: @JabanBaroose the term $P_{\ce{H2O}}$ in the denominator of the equation should have a power of 2, since the coefficient of $\ce{H2O}$ in balanced chemical equation is 2.

Comment: @Eyyboss Thank you for your reply. I have already got the answer that I was looking for as it was a very simple error that I made. Since Poutnik here couldn't help me out, I asked an online friend of mine who really helped me clarify the mistake that I made. But I greatly appreciate you for giving me an answer, even if it is too late.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I'm late to answering your question but I had the same problem with my calculations and I figured out what I did wrong. You forgot in your Keq equation the exponents: (x)(2x)^2/(5-2x)^2 = 0.0064 and then you square root both sides and go from there until you get a quadratic equation and like you did before just use the quadratic formula to solve for x. Hope this helps